# Selenium element id not found

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a Java program for my job that logs into Paychex (via Chrome) and downloads reports for me. My code navigates to the website, but I'm stuck at that point. I am using Selenium Chrome web driver, and I am unable to locate the element id for the login field, despite me entering the correct name. I've spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail. I've tried finding the element by id, name, css, and xpath. Nothing has worked! Below is the website url and my code. Any assistance in accessing this element would be beyond appreciated.
Thanks!

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://myapps.paychex.com/landing_remote/login.do?TYPE=33554433"
        + "&REALMOID=06-fd3ba6b8-7a2f-1013-ba03-83af2ce30cb3&GUID=&SMAUTHREA"
        + "SON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=09PZJoiHr8jiAF1z4DL6SopY5OyRzoKSeZ4y"
        + "IhpJe7nkRdeIwtlMrg0rd7X3FRDM&TARGET=-SM-https%3a%2f%2fmyapps%2epa"
        + "ychex%2ecom%2f");    
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.id("USER"));
```

HTML :

```
<input name="USER" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="USER" required="" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Username" data-ng-model="user.username" data-payx-form-value="siteminder.username" data-ng-change="clearShowError()" data-payx-focus="">
```

Comment: where is your HTML?

Comment: Are you sure the html element id is USER?  I would press F12 in chrome, you the little curser icon in the developer tools and click on the input box for field, and see what its id is set too.

Comment: Sorry - I did that and here it is.<input name="USER" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="USER" required="" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Username" data-ng-model="user.username" data-payx-form-value="siteminder.username" data-ng-change="clearShowError()" data-payx-focus="">

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML, properly formatted (like you did with your code) so it's easier for future readers to find.

Answer (score 2):

You do have the correct ID but your desired element is in an `IFRAME`. Switch to the `IFRAME` first and then you should be able to access your element.

```
driver.get("https://myapps.paychex.com/");
driver.switchTo().frame("login");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("USER"))).sendKeys("MyUsername");
// do stuff but be sure to switch back to default content if you need to access elements outside the IFRAME
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```